# Does the [rad] tag need some love?

Tags: discussion, tags

[rad](/questions/tagged/rad) seems to be used for two different purposes:

- Rapid Application Development
- IBM Rational Application Developer

at least if I [trust this suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/308458).

A quick look through the questions revealed that that tag is used for both...thingys...as I'm not involved in that tag in any way...help?

Comment: That tag is rad, bro

Comment: This tag is in need of disambiguation...

Comment: It seemed to me that a *large* majority of the questions really are about IBM products in the WebSphere family or IBM sponsored development (Eclipse). We have  a similar problem in the assembler/assembly tag, where I often retag stray posts to .net-assembly.

Comment: Also apparently for [`RadTabStrip`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11411565/change-text-of-label-in-parent-page-by-clicking-button-inside-child-page-within)

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps splitting into [rad-development](/questions/tagged/rad-development)(synonym [rapid-application-development](/questions/tagged/rapid-application-development)) + [ibm-rad](/questions/tagged/ibm-rad) (synonym [rational-application-developer](/questions/tagged/rational-application-developer)/[ibm-rational-application-developer](/questions/tagged/ibm-rational-application-developer))? But then, I don't really know how to ensure newer/less observant users don't use the [rad](/questions/tagged/rad) tag once that's been fixed.

*Also, are those synonyms too long?*

Then how about:

[rapid-app-dev](/questions/tagged/rapid-app-dev)

and

[rational-app-dev](/questions/tagged/rational-app-dev)/[ibm-rational-app-dev](/questions/tagged/ibm-rational-app-dev)

?

Comment: Yeah all those synonyms are over 25 chars.

Comment: @Toomai Better tags now (see update)?